# If this question can be reworded [...] leave a comment

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I just noticed that the text for off-topic closure includes this sentence:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.

Does the second part ("leave a comment") actually make sense?  If the OP comments to clarify the question, is that comment brought to the attention of anyone, e.g., the close voters, or by adding the question to the reopen queue?

I know if there's a single other commentator an unaddressed comment will go in his or her mailbox, but I don't think this happens if there is more than one?

(I'm also assuming here that closed questions receive very few views, at least not unless they have an interesting title.  Perhaps I'm mistaken?)

Comment: Excellent question. I have always assumed *leave a comment* meant *ask for help* in that context, in a generic kind of way, i.e. not @pinging a specific user. Something like *Okay guys, I don't exactly follow what's so wrong with my question you had to close it, can you elaborate on that so I can fix it?*

Comment: *"please edit the question or leave a comment."* seems to be targeted at the person casting the vote, can't see that being what we want the op to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good catch. If a question is unclear we should be *discouraging* the OP from trying to clarify it with comments, not encouraging. They should clarify the question itself. Far too many new users reply to comments rather than editing their questions.